# How to troubleshoot Angular-cli build when no error are thrown

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot

I just upgraded my Angular application to version 5, which worked fine. However, once I upgraded a few other things (like @angular/cdk, @angular/material, typescript) I had to fix a bunch of bugs that came with the upgrade. Everything seems totally great when I run `ng serve` or `ng build --prod` (JIT and AOT builds) --there aren't any errors in the terminal and the application builds successfully. The application is then served on `localhost:4200` as expected, but the app doesn't seem to bootstrap and nothing at all is printed in the browser console.

What can I do to troubleshoot the problem? I don't have any errors to look into, I feel like I just have to guess what's wrong.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I had the same  issue in my application, upgrading Angular I upgarded also typescript, resulting in white screen of death.
After hours of investigation, I managed it to work adding "meta" information in config.js like this:

 meta: {
      'typescript': {
        "exports": "ts"
      }
    }

Comment: @PizzoniAlessio what is config.js in your case? My angular-cli project doesn't have such a file

Comment: For me this is nearly always an error in the template. E.g. something like the following where & should be &&:  *ngIf="!reset & !expired"

Comment: @Kildareflare it's usually an error in the template for me too.